hashicorp vault code 500 and error 1045 (28000)
How can I fix it?
Error reading database/creds/test-role: Error making API request.
URL:GET http://127.0.0.1:8201/v1/database/creds/test-role
Code: 500. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
      * Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'vaultuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I checked the user's permissions.
I rechecked the Vault configuration.
(
 vault write database/roles/test-role \
 db_name=test \
 creation_statements="CREATE USER '{{name}}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{{password}}'; GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO '{{name}}'@'%';" \
 default_ttl="1h" \
 max_ttl="24h")
)

And nothing helps.
I checked the user's permissions. I rechecked the Vault configuration.
None of this helped.
